# Visual C++ error with two projects: name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, gridview

I'm new to Visual C++. I have two separate projects (let's call the first Converter and the second TreeGridView). I have this line of code in the Converter project:

```
private: AdvancedDataGridView::TreeGridView^ treeGridView;
```

which throws this error on 'AdvancedDataGridView':

```
name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name
```

I think I understand the error - Visual C++ can't find a class or namespace called 'AdvancedDataGridView' right?

I have a separate Visual Studio project called TreeGridView which has 3 C# projects included in it. One of the projects has an assembly name of 'ExpandableGridView' and a default namespace of 'AdvancedDataGridView' and an output of type Class Library. Another project has an assembly name of AdvancedDataGridView and a default namespace of AdvancedDataGridView and an output type of Windows Application.

Being new to Visual C++ and the codebase I'm using, I'm not sure how to make the error go away. The TreeGridView project (the one with 3 c# projects) does generate an ExpandableGridView.dll file which I've added a reference to in my Converter project, but the error persists. Intellisense doesn't find AdvancedDataGridView at all. Any ideas?

**Additional info:** When adding the ExpandableGridView.dll as a reference, I get a yellow warning triangle icon on the reference and 'Full Path' in the properties says

```
 The "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.References.UnresolvedAssemblyReference" reference
 could not be resolved.
```

Comment: Is this really `c++` and not `c++-cli`?

Comment: @drescherjm - Not sure - is there a way to tell? I didn't write this codebase I'm currently using.

Comment: You seem to be using some form of managed c++.

Comment: The syntax `TreeGridView^ treeGridView` is not a valid C++ variable declaration; it is either C# or C++-CLI.

Comment: Definitely not C++. I removed that tag. I don't remember which language it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I had two references to the same ExpandableGridView dll file - got rid of both of them, then added the latest dll again - after that the error and warning I mentioned above went away.

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to XOR a type  with a variable? Pointers are declared using `type*`, not `type^`.

See http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/ for a tutorial on C and C++ pointers.

Comment: There are other languages `C++/something` with "managed pointers".